# How to send intent to let another app open my encrypted data?

Tags: android, android-intent, encryption

How to send intent to let another app open my encrypted data on Android?
Is it the only way that we decrypt the file and send the decrypted file via intent + grant uri?

Answer (score 0):

Finally we do it in the way that "decrypt the file and open it send the decrypted fd via intent + grant uri", and it works good.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, can you point me to any resource that shows how to implement it?

Comment: @mvrck sorry, but it is our company code... u can google "android grant uri"